# how to change the name of a file with quilt

Tags: debian, quilt

I am trying to solve a bug in a Debian package, but to fix this bug I need to change the name of a file in the source. This package uses the format 3.0 (quilt).
How do I create a patch for changes a file name?

Answer (score 1):

I show you an example for a lib file

First you need to edit the Makefile and change this line (for a lib in this case)

```
LIBS = -lfoo -lanotherlib
```

then create debian/patches/foo.patch

```
dquilt new foo.patch

dquilt add Makefile

sed -i -e 's/-lfoo/-lbar/g' Makefile

dquilt refresh

dquilt header -e
```

...description of your patch here.....

and finaly build it